# google apps script how to schedule a trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function that accepts parameter from a different function. How to schedule this function as a trigger?

```js
function runData(){
  return googleApps.appsImport('table')
  }

function appsImport(sourcetable){
  //push data from table to sheet
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger another function to call appsImport with the parameter you want.

```
function runTrigger(){
  appsImport('table');
}

function appsImport(sourcetable){
  //push data from table to sheet
 }
```